# How do I make this Java code operate properly? [Multi-threaded, race condition]

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

I got this code from a student, and it does not work properly because of a race condition involving `x++` and `x--`.  He added `synchronized` to the `run()` method trying to get rid of this bug, but obviously this only excludes threads from entering `run()` on the **same** object (which was never a problem in the first place) but doesn't prevent independent objects from updating the same static variable `x` at the same time.

```
public class DataRace implements Runnable {
  static volatile int x;

  public synchronized void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
          x++;
          x--;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread [] threads = new Thread[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        threads[i] = new Thread(new DataRace());
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        threads[i].start();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        threads[i].join();

    System.out.println(x); // x not always 0!
  }
}
```

Since we cannot synchronize on `x` (because it is primitive), the best solution I can think of is to create a new static object like `static String lock = "";` and enclose the `x++` and `x--` within a `synchronized` block, locking on `lock`.  But this seems really awkward.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need to synchronize both operations `x++` and `x--` at the same time or separately? By the way, using a lock to solve this problem doesn't seem awkward (at least not to me).

Comment: replace `int` with `AtomicInteger` or synchronize on `DataRace.class`

Comment: ..or you can use the "class object". i.e. to use DataRace.class as a monitor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) does what you want, and it makes explicit the intent to have operations on `x` be atomic.  After quite a few runs of the following, I got `0`'s every time:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class DataRace implements Runnable {
    static volatile AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            x.incrementAndGet();
            x.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
            threads[i] = new Thread(new DataRace());
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
            threads[i].start();
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
            threads[i].join();

        System.out.println(x); // x **is now** always 0!
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need `synchronized`, since you don't look at `x` until the end. Without `synchronized`, you're saying the JVM is allowed to intersperse the method calls however it likes -- there could be two increments in a row followed by two decrements. But that's fine, because as long as the total number of increments is the same as the total number of decrements, and as long as each increment/decrement is atomic (which `AtomicInteger` guarantees), the final sum will still be 0. If you wanted to check for 0 at the end of each loop, then you would `synchronized` on some static lock.

Comment: @yshavit, you're absolutely right, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @yshavit He didn't need `synchronized` because it only stopped two threads from executing on the **same object** which (as I mentioned in my original post) never happens: each of the 100 created objects is operated on by its own thread.  You are correct that if we wanted to print `x` at the end of each loop we'd need another synchronization mechanism to ensure the inc's and dec's always ran in atomic pairs.

Answer (score 1):

[AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` is static and reside in a class, so access to it should be synchronized on that class: either make a static method, or use synchronized block on `DataRace.class`.